# How to order a title that contains numbers at the beginning

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Usually when I use "`titles.where(status: 1).order("name")`", it correctly orders titles like:

```
"1. title one"
"2. title two"
```

but when titles like:

```
"1.1. Random title"
```

this puts it at the end of the ordering when it should go after "1. title one" and before "2. title two". What could I do there?

Comment: Ordering is lexigraphic; you'd need a custom comparator (which may also be possible on the DB side depending on the DB and where you want to keep the logic) that breaks the string up and compares first by numeric tuples then the title itself.

Comment: Are all your titles like that? Maybe you can keep the title without those numbers and store them separately in a "chapters" column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is sort it by casting the first part to decimal and then sorting based on that column. Something like this

```rb
titles.where(status: 1).order("cast(left(name,LOCATE('. ',name,1)-1) as  decimal(5,2))")
```

What this will do is

- remove everything in name after and including `.`
- cast the remaining name to decimal
- Then sort based on that value

Comment: This solution is correct, but suppose that the titles are not only going to have that format, if someone puts a normal title, is there also the possibility of ordering them alphabetically and numerically?

Comment: Yes, that is the downside of this solution that you need to have a consistent format or else it won't work properly. And yes you can extract the part after the number and sort on that too. What you can do is 

```IF(cast(left(name,LOCATE('. ',name,1)-1) as  decimal(5,2)), cast(left(name,LOCATE('. ',name,1)-1) as  decimal(5,2)), 100),name;
```

change 100 with some large number this will move all the names without number to the end, and then sort them by alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
titles.where(status: 1).sort_by{|title| title.name.split(" ").first.to_f}
```

Essentially it is creating a custom sort by grabbing that first number and converting it to a float to sort by

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code already worked as intended.
For example, if you run this code, it will give the result as in the photo:

```
titles = Title.where(status: 1).order("name").map(&:name)

puts titles.join("\n")
```

[image]